# Rpy2 on Linux. "R library contains no packages"-Error

Tags: python, r, rpy2, r-package

I tried installing rpy2 but it couldn't load any packages.

My Linux is Mint 20,

Python 3.8.2,

R 3.6.3,
rpy2 3.3.5 (installed with pip, by the way)

I remember I followed someone saying how to install R packages from within python and this is what I did:

```
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1)

packnames= ("ggplot2", "hexbin")
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector
# R vector of strings (idk what it does)

names_to_install= [x for x in packnames if not rpackages.isinstalled(x)] 
if len(names_to_install) > 0:
    utils.install_packages(StrVector(names_to_install))
quit()

# It will create a WARNING as such: 
# R[write to console]:  'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable

# Would you like to use a personal library instead? (yes/No/cancel) yes
# Would you like to create a personal library
# ‘~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
# to install packages into? (yes/No/cancel) yes

# SO JUST SAY YES TWICE AND IT WILL CREATE A NEW FOLDER FOR YOUR INSTALLED PACKAGES!!
```

Well ok so my packages were installed in /R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6

But I've changed that later, when I tried some test code from the internet, I got a warning that I have no packages.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.8

import rpy2

print("rpy2 version is:", rpy2.__version__)
# >>rpy2 version is: 3.3.5

import rpy2.robjects as robjects

                    # R PACKAGES
# rpy2 is providing a function rpy2.robjects.packages.importr()
# that makes that step very similar to importing Python packages.

from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr  

base = importr('base')
utils = importr('utils')


from rpy2.robjects import Formula, Environment
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import IntVector, FloatVector
from rpy2.robjects.lib import grid
from rpy2.robjects.packages import data
from rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded import RRuntimeError
import warnings

# The R 'print' function
rprint = robjects.globalenv.find("print")
stats = importr('stats')
grdevices = importr('grDevices')
datasets = importr('datasets')

grid.activate()
```

The warning was:

```
R[write to console]: Warning messages:

R[write to console]: 1: 
R[write to console]: In (function (package, help, pos = 2, lib.loc = NULL, character.only = FALSE,  :
R[write to console]: 
 
R[write to console]:  library ‘/usr/lib/R/site-library’ contains no packages

R[write to console]: 2: 
R[write to console]: In (function (package, help, pos = 2, lib.loc = NULL, character.only = FALSE,  :
R[write to console]: 
 
R[write to console]:  library ‘/usr/lib/R/site-library’ contains no packages
```

then I tried to install the packages from R, so I sudo opened R and typed
`install.packages()`
for some packages like base, utils, grDevices..., which count as base packages, it said it doesn't update it for that reason. But I found out their path is "/usr/lib/R/library"

then for other packages I wanted to install, like ggplot2, it installed it into "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library", which is what was wanted in the first installing step.

neither of those are what rpy2 wanted. It wanted /usr/lib/R/site-library

But I even found out I can add a path when importing a package like this:

```
base = importr('base', lib_loc="/usr/lib/R/library")
```

it worked kind of.
I've tested my code from above (second box) line by line and I've added it for all packages imported with importr.
And most of the `from x import y` worked aswell. Just not grid.
`from rpy2.robjects.lib import grid`
still gave me the same "library ‘/usr/lib/R/site-library’ contains no packages" message.
But I don't know how to add a path there!!

My Prof and I tried to find a solution for 2 days now. I am really desperate.
Why are the paths even such an issue? I saw noone talking about that the default paths it chooses are not correct, and everything I found was just for windows! If the defaults are not correct, shouldn't that be in the documentation? And if it just works for everyone else, what have I done wrong?

[R library contains no packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49108205/r-library-contains-no-packages)
was a similar question, but his rpy2 wanted to use usr/local/lib, which would be correct in my case!! (and there was not really an answer, at least nothing that I understood)

Comment: Perhaps this helps setting up rpy2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61622624/how-to-correctly-set-up-rpy2/62986815#62986815

Answer (score 2):

R can be installed in quite a few ways, and the default directory that will receive the packages can be specified at configure (and may be install) time. If you R installed for the full system, and assuming that this is the only R installed, we will call it the "system R" and the directory in which R is installed, the default ("recommended") packages are installed, and additional packages will be installed are under `/usr`. If you you are using a precompiled and packaged R (e.g., RPM or deb) the exact location will depend on that binary package. Writing in that directory will often require elevated privileges, which is why you need `sudo`.

In addition to that directory, it is possible to specify additional directories in which R packages should be installed. This is was is happening when R prompts you with an offer to use a user-local directory. (note: your packages are then installed in `~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6`, not `/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6`). When in R, the command `.libPaths()` will tell you where R is looking for its packages, and the R doc for that function will list how R get that information.

In the end you are listing a few directories with packages, or no packages, or where packages might have been installed in your question:

- `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`
- `~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6`
- `/usr/lib/R/site-library`
- `/usr/lib/R/library`

There is almost certainly confusion about where your installed packages, and where you thought they were installed. Since you `sudo`, at some point I suggest that you uninstall and reinstall R, install packages in a personal library as R suggests it, and set the environment variable `R_LIBS_USER` to point out to that directory (see [automatically create personal library in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879424/automatically-create-personal-library-in-r)).